# String Interview

Tags: java, string

If I have code like below is it feasible?

```
String b = "abc";
String c = "def";
for (int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
    String a = b + c; // i got a different object , ahhh!
}
```

How does it affect the system? Can we improve it and how?

Doesn't that follow String pool concept, since i am creating String without new operator i'm ending with 1 object, in result it was creating 100000000 object(i was wrong) but i didn't unserstand how (checked with **==** operator)

for example

```
final String b = "abc";
final String c = "def";
for (int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
    String a = b + c; //same object referred again and again
}
```

gives same object , i was able to check with **==** operator

Isn't that both the example follow String pool concept? Why does if i have final for my String variable varies the outcome of different object or same object .

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: good one: http://kaioa.com/node/59

Comment: this was an interview question, so he was checkin what this guy got on String , i was unable to get a picture with final String variable and just String variable .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `b` and `c` are not marked `final`, the compiler probably assumes that at some point in the code, different strings might be assigned to those variables. As such, when you write `a=b+c`, the compiler can't assume anything about the contents of `b` and `c` (they could even come from the user) so it has to concatenate them and produce a brand new string.

When they're `final`, the compiler can know for sure that `b` is always `"abc"` and `c` is always `"def"`, and possibly even infer that `(b+c)=="abcdef"`, and as such put it in a pool or simply do the concatenation before the loop.

Comment: the value you get at runtime will be maintained in String pool (at first time), right ? so how can you get 10000000 object instead you must get 1 object only which is referred again and again !!

Comment: Why it's not reusing from the pool ??? after creating it once

Comment: If you run your class through `javap -c`, you'll see that in the case where you write `final` the compiler puts in `"abcdef"` as a constant. I'm not entirely sure exactly when things are put in the string pool, but my guess is it refers mostly to compile-time constants. I assume that if every string went into the pool, that would impose a penalty, because you'd still have to create the string before you can check that it's already in the pool (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 1):

When `b` and `c` are final `b + c` is a [constant expression](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.28). Which means the + operaion is done at compile name. The line is then equivallent to

```
String a = "abcdef";
```

When `b` and `c` are non-final, their value is no longer considered constant expression and string concatenation is done at runtime and new String is created at each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

> How does it affect the system? Can we improve it and how?

Strings are immutable, i.e., It creates (or reuses from the pool) a new String object each time you concatenate. Use a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) Object if you're doing looping concatenations.

```
String b = "abc";
String c = "def";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=0;i<100000000;i++){
    sb.append(b);
    sb.append(c);
}
result = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

"b" and "c" are stored in pool. But "a" is created each time. Use StringBuilder to prevent it.

Just to help you better understand it

```
Object b = new Object(); //b created only once
Object c = new Object(); //c created only once

for(int i = 0; i < 100500; i++) {
    MyClass a = new MyClass(b, c); //a created each loop
}
```

Same with strings.

As Vlad mentioned -- in case of strings "b + c" would produce new object each time if they are not final